# Tooltip with input textbox

Tags: .net, wpf

In my WPF application a user can click on a canvas and have a point drawn on it. I would like to have a custom tooltip-like control that would pop up over that point and have an input field where the user would assign some integer value to that point before drawing other points.

How would I do that?

Comment: use popup for example, or tooltip. what is the problem?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt Can a tooltip have an input field?

Comment: Yes, it can, just use content instead of text. The problem is that Tooltip is a bit difficult to configure. it doesn't give ability to configure active time, or open close manually... so I would recommend to use Popup control instead.